# SonarQube - How to detect copy pasting of code between projects?

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarQube how to detect copy pasting between projects?

There is CPD analysis running for every module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `General Settings > General` and set "Cross project duplication detection
" to true.

You can also set it directly in your config file.

`sonar.cpd.cross_project = true`